# Formula for probability-probability plot

Tags: probability, data-visualization

I am programmer developing a Software that features the display of a probability plot. As far as I know there are 2 different ways to display a probability plot (please correct me if I say something wrong):

- A Percent / Percent Chart
- A Quantile / Quantile Chart

My customers want a Percent / Percent Chart. That brings some problems.  There is no charting control I know that features a probability plot chart.

[image]

That's why I have to calculate the positions of the data points by hand. **Are there any formulas or calculations to place the data points and Y-axis values in a normal coordinate system?**

Comment: I don't know what programming language you are using, but [here](http://code.google.com/p/bridgescour/source/browse/qqplot.py?r=f08878af3123c5959a7f11220946f4938cbe7130) is some python code to make a QQ plot.

Comment: Hey I am using C#. The display of a QQ chart would be pretty easy since the axis are linear. The Axis in the chart above seems to be kinda (double) logarithmic, thats what giving me headaches.

Comment: The y-axis is transformed according to the Normal cumulative density function, $F(y)=\int_{-\infty}^y \exp(-t^2/2) dt / \sqrt{2\pi}$, as multiplied by $100$ to convert to percent. In the illustration it spans the range from (approximately) $y=-3$ to $y=3$, giving $F(y)$ ranging from about $0.3$% to $99.7$%.

Comment: What you have there is actually a Q-Q plot; it's just that the y-*axis* is marked with the corresponding percentile-ranks rather than the quantiles. A P-P plot is different.

Answer (score 1):

What you have displayed in your question is actually a Q-Q plot; it's just that the y-*axis* is marked with the corresponding percentile-ranks rather than the quantiles.

That is, that y-axis has tickmarks at $\Phi^{-1}(p)$ but labels of $p$. The plotted points are still actually a Q-Q plot.

A P-P plot is different. It would transform the y-axis to be linear in $p$ and apply a similar transformation to the data (after standardizing).